# Using Laravel and Eloquent, get the most recent values through a parent table

Tags: laravel, eloquent

With Laravel and eloquent ORM - is there a way from within the model to do the following:

eg. I have a collections table. It has a collection_type property.
If I select a row from the collections model, i need to also select the 10 most recent records from the table that corresponds to the collection_type value. So if the value was post then it would select the 10 most recent records from the posts table.

I thought the following methods in the collection model would work:

```
  public function most_recent(){
    $collection_type_class = Relation::getMorphedModel($this->collection_type);
    return $collection_type_class::orderBy("id", "DESC")->take(10)->get();
  }
  protected $with = ['most_recent'];
```

If it helps the structure might look a little like this:

```
collections:{'id','collection_type'} //collection_type=['post'||'page'||'testimonial']

posts:{'id','title','snippet','post'...etc },
pages:{'id','title','meta'...etc },
testimonials:{'id','name','testimonial'...etc }
```

Comment: `$with` is supposed to be for relationships. your `most_recent()` function returns a `Collection`. Have you defined a polymorphic relationship in your model that uses the `collection_id` and `collection_type`  fields?

Comment: As an aside, can you edit your question with the structure of the table involved?

Comment: Thanks IGP, I hear what you saying, but there is no collection_id to setup the relationship - I just need the most recent values based on the collection_type. I had hoped to do this within the model.

Answer (score 0):

I have figured it out. The problem was that $this->collection_type didn't have a value when using with, I need to use an accessor like so:

```
// APPENDS - ADDS A PROPERTY TO A MODEL
protected $appends = ['collection'];

// ACCESSOR FORMAT getXyzAttribute
// ACCESSOR - USED IN LARAVEL TO MODIFY A VALUE WHEN THEY ARE ACCESSED - WHICH IN MY CASE ALLOWS ME TO GET THE OTHER ROWS BASED ON THE COLLECTION_TYPE
// WHEN USING THE ACCESSOR the collection_type HAS ACTUALY GOT A VALUE
public function getCollectionAttribute()
{
    $relatedModel = Relation::morphMap()[$this->collection_type];
    return $relatedModel::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->limit(10)->get();                
}
```